Declension in book dedication
If I want to write a book dedication to my son, name xxx, shall I say
Meinem Sohn, xxx
or
An meinen Sohn, xxx
?

If you bought a book and want to write a few lines on one of the front pages, I'd choose:

Für meinen Sohn xxx...

If you wrote the entire book yourself, and the dedication is printed as part of the book, you might use like you suggested

Meinem Sohn xxx

as an alternative to the version with "für". "Meinem Sohn xxx..." is probably an ellipsis of "Meinem Sohn xxx gewidmet" and a higher register and has - to my ears at least in the shortened version - a bit dated sound
The "An meinen Sohn xxx..." is a addressee direction like writing on the envelope of a letter or so.
